# Google Sheets App Script: e.range is null when onChange function is run via a trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, onchange

This question got me banned from asking questions... what did I do wrong?! I really don't understand.

I am bashing my head against my keyboard.

This seems like it should be simple... but I continue to get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getNumColumns' of undefined**
> at onChange(checkBoxes:5:20)

The goal would be to click a check box, get a date stamp, but I need to also check the column header (Row 4) to determine what function to run next...
However, I can not get that far because I need to know the column of the cell that triggered the function.

```
  function onChange(e) {
    const range = e.range;
    Logger.log(range.getNumColumns());
  };

/**Trigger:
     Head:= Deployment
     Event:= From spreadsheet - On change
     Function:= onChange
     Error rate:= 100% */
```

Technically speaking I can use `activecell` but I am concerned that users are unreliable, what happens if they check a check box in col:1 then click to col:2, will `activecell` return col:1, or 2?

I have tried a verity of combinations to solve this, but each time it says "Cannot read property 'getNumColumns' of undefined"

I have tried the following:

```
e.range.columnStart
```

Comment: onChange has no e.range it has an e.source. Try using this in the row right after the declaration. `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));` it will show you what is in the event object after a trigger fires.

Comment: I've played around with onChange a lot recently and even with e.source if you are trying to get the active range or the active sheet, then don't bother because you are always going to get `e.source.getSheets()[0];`

Comment: If you are trying to detect checkboxes then I would recommend using onEdit() trigger instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.range // is the location of the edit it could be more than one cell if it's something like a paste.
  e.range.getSheet() // is the sheet 
  e.range.columnStart // is the column of the edited cell
  e.range.rowStart // is the row of the edited cell
  e.range.columnEnd // is the last column in e.range
  e.range.rowEnd // is the last row in e.range
  e.source // is the active spreadsheet
  e.oldValue // is the value before the change
  e.value // is the value after the edit
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); // will provide a description of the entire event object
}
```

There are others like authorization level and user information sometimes

Comment: ```e.range.columnStart``` gives me the same error

Comment: You cannot run this function it's just an explanation of the values in the event object and you can't really run this type of function without the event object provided by the trigger

Comment: Thank you, I am starting to understand. Is there a way to get the column id from the event location? so i can say if the change happened in col:1 run function(ABC) else...

Comment: If you have only edited one cell the the column is `e.range.columnStart` and the row is `e.range.rowStart`  so the cell would be `e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).getValue();` and that same value would be `e.value`